# Leaks in navigationcontroler when puching it

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

i have found leaks in the below code at particular area, means when i push my view from other sides, There is not any leak i found but only this push give me 100%leak.

```
actionsListing *View = [[actionsListing alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:View animated:YES];
[View release];
```

What will i do thanks.

Comment: All this doesn't make sense. Please make your classes start with uppercase, and instances with lowercase letters. Don't call a view controller (is it?) *view*. All this makes the code the perfect place to hide bugs, and for other people it's impossible to read.

Comment: Agree with Eiko - your naming scheme is the exact opposite of the standard ;) your first line should look something like `ActionsListing *controller = [[ActionsListing alloc] init];` - Classes start with uppercase, instances start with lowercase. And calling a controller a view is just plain misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is fine - you're doing everything correctly.

Are you testing in the simulator or on a device? If it's the simualtor, *don't*. The simulator has a different memory model and reports leaks that aren't really there; always test for leaks on a device :)

If you still get leaks, you're retaining the view controller somewhere else by mistake - that code is definitely correct.

Comment: Thax i was using simulator :)

Comment: Yea, it's really annoying - I wish they would pop up a warning telling you profiling for leaks won't work!